# Change auto-awarded bounty after grace period

Tags: discussion, answers, bounty

A bounty I had set to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29380336/set-compiler-optimization-selectively-for-template-headers) was auto-awarded by the system just now, right before I got home.

I was indeed going to award it to the person who actually won, but I'd like to do it myself (for giving the full rep to the user and also to earn the associated badge), but I missed it because of a few minutes. Didn't do it before because I really had a hard time choosing between two of the answers.

Just to be sure, is there anything I can do in this case? I do recognized I shouldn't have delayed this decision to the last minute.

**Update:** Lesson learned the hard way this time. I appreciate the commentaries and also hope this serves as an example for delayers like myself.

Comment: anything you can do? Be more mindful of when it times out and act accordingly? I don't know if flagging your question explaining the issue will do anything...

Comment: You have an entire week, and the only answer with a bounty awarded was posted 8 days ago...

Comment: If you had accepted their answer, they would have gotten it all even on auto-award...

Comment: @Deduplicator But I didn't accept any for the same reason, delaying the choice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Just to be sure, is there anything I can do in this case? I do recognized I shouldn't have delayed this decision to the last minute.

Next time, don't do that. The whole point of the **grace period** is to give you a heads-up that you're very, very close to losing control over your bounty; continuing to put off the decision at that point is like having to switch to the reserve fuel tank on your bike and then... driving past the next fuel station. There's nothing we can do to fix it; you pushed your luck and lost.